# Multiple foreign keys and multiple constrains

Tags: sql, oracle, database-administration

Let's assume I have a table called boxes with the box_id attribute as the PK.

There are two other tables. The first one is red_boxes and the second blue_boxes.

I have added a constraint to the red_boxes table

```
ALTER TABLE red_boxes
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_box_id
FOREIGN KEY (box_id)
REFERENCES boxes (box_id);
```

Now, I would like to add a constraint to the blue_boxes table. The SQL structure would look like the following, if I did not add the constraint already to the the red_boxes. The obvious way to fix this is to name a new constraint differently e.g. `fk_box_id2`, but is this is a good way? Am I supposed to somehow re-use the previous constraint, or this is not possible, why?

```
ALTER TABLE blue_boxes
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_box_id
FOREIGN KEY (box_id)
REFERENCES boxes (box_id)
```

Comment: The constraint name is the ID that identify the constraint it is like a PK for constraints (just as an example). Therefore you cannot have two constraints with the same name. A good pratice is to name the constraint with part of the table that it belong like `fk_boxid#redbox` and `fk_boxid#bluebox` (the # is just a convention that I use) be carefull to not extrapolate the name limit with, in oracle, if I recall is 30 characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each constraint is separate and requires a unique name. My recommendation is to use the source and destination table names, for example `fk_red_boxes_boxes` and `fk_blue_boxes_boxes`. This way you can easily identify where they come from and where they go to.

*If you have underscores in your table names, you might want to come up with a modified convention that you can easily understand at a glance. For example, a double underscore: `fk__blue_boxes__boxes` and `fk__red_boxes__boxes`.*

Comment: I prefer Jorge's idea of using another character, e.g. $ or # - makes better use of the 30-char limit.